# Create numpy array with repeat pattern

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

What is the best way to create a numpy array with the following data:

`my_array = [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], ... , [1, 2 ,3]]`

with [1, 2, 3] repeated about 100 times.

I have made some test with tile, repat, etc. but result is always [1, 2, 3, 1 ,2, 3, 1, 2, etc.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use list comprehension:

```
my_array = np.array([[1,2,3] for i in range(100)])
```

This writes `[1,2,3]` a hundred times in a list and converts it to a numpy array

Comment: Works fine, thx